# Android MVVM databinding set error in editext issue

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

According to our structure i am using MVVM architecture with databinding. Its working fine and i am creating login page. i want to set error in `Editext` on click of submit button so i used this code inside view model class -

```
 public boolean isEmailAndPasswordValid(String email, String password) {
        // validate email and password
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!CommonUtils.isEmailValid(email)) {
            return  false;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            return  false;
        }
        return  true;
    }
```

now i want to set error on click of login button which id exist inside `Activity` class , how could i get the view id inside viewmodel class. i think it will be bad idea to pass binding object inside viewmodel class, so how could i  achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of LiveData and instead of returning true or false from your isEmailAndPasswordValid method inside your viewmodel class, you could post values to the live data instead.

So instead of doing return true or return false, you do myLiveData.postValue(true) or myLiveData.postValue(false). This way, you could observe this liveData in your view and once the live data value changes you can make UI changes accordingly. For more information look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Hope it helps! :)